# Pattern matching with enum in Rust

Tags: rust, pattern-matching

I'm doing some Rust exercises and I'm struggling a lot. Hope I'm not the only one.

I'm searching for a way to match the pattern for only the coins that have a state.

```rust
Coin::*(state) => result.push_str(format!("{:?} from {:?}", coin, state).as_str()),
```

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
pub enum State {
    Alabama,
    Alaska
}

#[derive(Debug)]
#[allow(dead_code)]
pub enum Coin {
    Penny,
    Nickel,
    Dime,
    Quarter(State)
}

fn main() {
    let coin = Coin::Quarter(State::Alabama);
    let penny = Coin::Penny;
    get_coin_information(&penny);
    get_coin_information(&coin);
}

pub fn get_coin_information(coin: &Coin)
{
    let mut result = String::from("The coin is a ");

    match coin {
        Coin::*(state) => result.push_str(format!("{:?} from {:?}", coin, state).as_str()),
        other => result.push_str(format!("{:?}", other).as_str())
    }

    let result = result + ".";

    println!("{}", result);
}
```

Comment: There is only _one_ coin that has a state, you can specify it directly. In case there are more, you can use or patterns (`Coin::A(state) | Coin::B(state) => ...`).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman answer is the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such pattern.

See [pattern chapter of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html) for more information about patterns, and the [patterns reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/patterns.html) for their grammar. No pattern allows a wildcard in this position.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there are two issues in this task arising from the example, one that Chayim Friedman and mcarton hinted at and the display of type information as string.
What mcarton has provided is very helpful.

Your code with a little modification will also work

[https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=af81626a5caeaedf49866ed2346e3948](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9f6ca2e027b15025fbcdf7039b654120)

```
use std::fmt::{self, Debug, Display};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum State {
    Alabama,
    Alaska
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Coin {
    Penny,
    Nickel,
    Dime,
    Quarter(State)
}

impl Display for State {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}

impl Display for Coin {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "{:?}", self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let coin = Coin::Quarter(State::Alabama);
    let penny = Coin::Penny;
    get_coin_information(&penny);
    get_coin_information(&coin);
}

pub fn get_coin_information(coin: &Coin)
{
    

    match coin {
        //It is written so that it is easy to debug.
       Coin::Penny | Coin::Nickel | Coin::Dime  => {
            let msg = format!("The coin status {}", coin);
            println!("{}", msg);
        },
        _ => {
            println!("The coin status other {:?}", coin);
        }
    }

}
```